# Redis - ERR unknown command 'EVAL'

Tags: asp.net, .net, redis, asp.net-core-2.0, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to use redis cache (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis) with .net core 2.1 and for that purpose I had followed this tutorial https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/06/using-redis-cache-net-core/ Now the issue is when I am trying to Get data using _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key) I am getting this error "ERR unknown command 'EVAL'". I have also searched for this kind of error and found that this could happen because of older version of Redis but I am using latest version of Microsoft.Extension.Caching.Redis (version 2.1.1)

Here is my code:

```
         public async Task<string> RetrieveCache(string key)
        {
            var data = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
                return "";

            return data;
        }
```

appsettings.json:

```
  "RedisServer": {
    "Server": "12.66.909.61:6379,password=pwd",
    "InstanceName": "Store.Toys"
  }
```

and startup.cs

```
 services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
            {
                option.Configuration = Configuration["RedisServer:Server"];
                option.InstanceName = Configuration["RedisServer:InstanceName"];
            });
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

The **server** needs to support the feature; it sounds like the *server* that you're targeting lacks support for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Eval command according to documentation is supported since redis server version 2.6. 
You can find out what version do you have now on your remote server by

```
$ telnet 12.66.909.61 6379
#and type 
info
```

or using redis client - redis-cli -h 12.66.909.61 -p 6379 -a pwd info
You will get

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.24
...
```

Then you will need to upgrade redis-server package on your server upto 2.6

Comment: Hi, I have redis_version: 5.0.9, still I'm getting the error.. Any other solution?

Comment: @jitesh2796, I'm using .Net and the issue was the connector package. in my case, project 3.1 and the packages were 5.*x . it solved when used packages 3.x